# RecyclerView работает некорректно

Tags: android, recyclerview

Проблема в том, что когда я помещаю в него 6 и более элементво он перестаёт работать правильно.Опишу принцип работы моего списка. В нем отображаются некоторые элементы так же доступна функция выделения и удаления элементов. С выделением-то и происходят проблемы. Когда в списке до 6 элементов, то всё хорошо, а когда 6 или больше, то выделяться начинается почему-то элемент, который находится на 2 позиции выше. Как это объяснить? Ниже приведу полный код для RecyclerVew и код, где я выделяю элементы.

RecyclerView

```
class DictionaryItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
    View.OnLongClickListener {

TextView tvTranslate;
TextView tvWord;
TextView tvTranscript;

protected Context context;

DictionaryItemViewHolder(Context context, final View itemView){
    super(itemView);

    this.context = context;
    tvTranslate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dict_translate);
    tvWord = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_word);
    tvTranscript = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dict_transcription);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (DictionaryItemAdapter.onClickListener!= null)
        DictionaryItemAdapter.onClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getLayoutPosition(), v);
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (DictionaryItemAdapter.onLongClickListener != null)
        DictionaryItemAdapter.onLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(itemView, getLayoutPosition(), v);
    return true;
}
}

/**
 *
 */
class DictionaryItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DictionaryItemViewHolder> {

static OnItemClickListener onClickListener;
static OnItemLongClickListener onLongClickListener;
private ArrayList<DictionaryItem> initialList = new ArrayList<>();

private ArrayList<DictionaryItem> items;

DictionaryItemAdapter(ArrayList<DictionaryItem> items){
    this.items = items;
}

void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    onClickListener = listener;
}

void setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
    onLongClickListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DictionaryItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvTranscript.setText(items.get(position).getTranscription());
    holder.tvTranslate.setText(items.get(position).getTranslate());
    holder.tvWord.setText(items.get(position).getWord());
}

@Override
public DictionaryItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.dictionary_activity_list_item, parent, false);

    return new DictionaryItemViewHolder(parent.getContext(), view);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

void removeChecked(){
    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
        items.get(i).setCheckedElement(false);
    }
}

//TODO: Сделать сохранение удаляемых элементов.

void deleteCheckedElements() {
    int i = 0;

    while(i != items.size()) {
        if (items.get(i).isCheckedElement()) {
            items.remove(i);
            super.notifyItemRemoved(i);
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
}

public  ArrayList<DictionaryItem> getInitialList (){
    return initialList;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return items.isEmpty();
}
}
```

Методы для выделения элемента:

```
 @Override
public void onItemLongClick(View itemView, int position, View v) {
    if (!isSearch) {
        try {
            //Сохраняем список элементов перед удалением
            initialListOfItems = copy(items);
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!isCheckableList) {
            //Если список uncheckable, значит обновляем меню тулбара и устанавливаем режим удаления
            menu.clear();
            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dictionary_inflated_menu, menu);
            isCheckableList = true;
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Добавляем жлемент
        addCheckedElement(itemView, position);
    }
}

void addCheckedElement(View itemView, int i) {
    DictionaryItem item = items.get(i);
    if (item.isCheckedElement()) {
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.darkWhite,
                null));
        item.setCheckedElement(false);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else {
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
                R.color.selectedItemBackground, null));
        selectedItems.add(i);
        item.setCheckedElement(true);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: пришло время узнать о переиспользовании айтемов в списках, почему виджет называется **Recycler**View и алгоритмом его работы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `DictionaryItemViewHolder` в реализациях `onClick` и `onLongClick` замените `getLayoutPosition` на `getAdapterPosition`.

И еще: позиция добавляется в некий `selectedItems`, затем адаптер уведомляется об изменения данных, но в `onBindViewHolder` я не вижу кода для установки фона айтему. При прокрутке у вас будут пропадать отмеченные элементы.

Измените `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DictionaryItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DictionaryItem item = items.get(position);
    holder.tvTranscript.setText(item.getTranscription());
    holder.tvTranslate.setText(item.getTranslate());
    holder.tvWord.setText(item.getWord());
    if (item.isCheckedElement()) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.darkWhite, null));
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.selectedItemBackground, null));
    }
}
```

P.S если не поможет, пишите ниже

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, по-прежнему работает некорректно

Comment: А что за ограничение? Почему именно 6? Сколько на экран влезает? 6?

Comment: А что с холдером? Почему он помимо `View` принимает контекст? Уберите его, оставьте только `View`. А контекст передавайте в адаптер. Просто попробуйте, потому что все вроде верно, а тут я вижу несоответствие дефолту

Comment: Я не знаю почему ограничение на 6. У меня элементы не фиксированного размера, на эеран всегда по разному влазит, но после 6-го элемента всегда всё слетает

Comment: Так, всё теперь работает

Comment: Но теперь появилась немного другая проблема м.б. перейдем в чат?

Comment: Я не знаю как) эээ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57619/discussion-between-flippy-and-).